# Saml 2.0 SSO - Receiving HTTP ERROR 400 when directed to ACS URL

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, service-provider

I have an app that I have developed as the SP, using Salesforce as the IdP.

I am testing it out (localhost) so have used ngrok to expose the Api.

I have made sure that I am referencing ngrok in the code and have updated the ACS Url in Salesforce - Connected App.

Use Case:

1. AuthnRequest is generated at the SP
2. Redirected to Idp (Salesforce) for authentication
3. Salesforce -> ACS Url

Is there something in the configuration that I need to do?

I can see the Request is generated successfully, and I can see a Response is sent from Salesforce by inspecting the payload.

I have checked the Saml Response sent back and it contains the user assertion, etc as expected.

The problem I have is when it loads the ACS Url, I get a HTTP Error 400 Bad Request when loading the page before it hits any backend code.

I can successfully load the ACS Url by just using the Url.